# Transform Identity Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have identity matrix which can be generated via `diag(5)`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

I want to convert it to the matrix wherein series starts after 1. For example 1st column, values 1 through  5. Second column - values 1 through 4.

**Desired Output**

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   0   0   0   0
[2,]    2   1   0   0   0
[3,]    3   2   1   0   0
[4,]    4   3   2   1   0
[5,]    5   4   3   2   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below (given `m <- diag(5)`)

```
> (row(m) - col(m) + 1)*lower.tri(m,diag = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    1    0    0    0
[3,]    3    2    1    0    0
[4,]    4    3    2    1    0
[5,]    5    4    3    2    1
```

---

Another option is using `apply` + `cumsum`

```
> apply(lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE), 2, cumsum)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    1    0    0    0
[3,]    3    2    1    0    0
[4,]    4    3    2    1    0
[5,]    5    4    3    2    1
```

Answer (score 5):

**1)** If d <- diag(5) is the identity matrix then:

```
pmax(row(d) - col(d) + 1, 0)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    1    0    0    0
[3,]    3    2    1    0    0
[4,]    4    3    2    1    0
[5,]    5    4    3    2    1
```

**2)** This alternative is slightly longer (though still a one-liner) but also works if the columns of d are rearranged and/or some columns are missing.  For example,

```
dd <- d[, 4:1] # test data
pmax(outer(1:nrow(dd) + 1, max.col(t(dd)), `-`), 0)
```

giving the same result for d and this for dd:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    2
[3,]    0    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3    4
[5,]    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution based on nested `cumsum`:

```r
n <- 5
m <- diag(n)

apply(m, 2, function(x) cumsum(cumsum(x)))

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    2    1    0    0    0
#> [3,]    3    2    1    0    0
#> [4,]    4    3    2    1    0
#> [5,]    5    4    3    2    1
```

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
x <- 1:5
embed(c(rep(0, length(x) - 1), x), length(x))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    1    0    0    0
[3,]    3    2    1    0    0
[4,]    4    3    2    1    0
[5,]    5    4    3    2    1
```